# Getting Bluetooth Adapter working with Xamarin for Android API 19 or above

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android

I am trying my first android project, but having trouble getting the BluetoothAdapter working. I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio with a nexus 5 emulator running Android 4.4 (API 19).

I tried the following code

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter; 
bluetoothAdapter.Enable();
```

And got an error message

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an > object

I also tried

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = (BluetoothAdapter)this.GetSystemService(Context.BluetoothService);
bluetoothAdapter.Enable();
```

and again got an error

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

This may be a very basic question, but it seems some of the support is outdated since as of Android 4.3 the bluetooth adapter is created in a new way.

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooh is not supported by the Android emulator, be it the Android SDK one or the Visual Studio Android emulator. It is so specified in the documentation.

Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#about